# I want to understand why my question was closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I'd like to understand why my question was closed so I can avoid that happening in the future (And of course to find a way to find an answer for the issue I'm having on the first place)

Thank you.

**Question:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582959/microstrategy-installation-not-showing-all-options-linux

Comment: Side note: please don't put [tag]s in your titles, that's what the tag section is for. (And tags at the end of it inside square braces look like close notices, so it's actually detrimental.)

Answer (score 5):

It was closed as off-topic, because it is not a programming question. It is probably more suitable for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). But read their [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq) before asking there, to see if it is on-topic there.

Comment: Well, the FAQ didn't really give me much insight. I believe it's a programming question because all we have done to fix this issue is shell programming related.

Comment: @Ryoku But that is not evident by the question. Maybe if you show your code for fixing the issue, and explain how it fails, it could be re-opened. No guarantees though.

Comment: @Ryoku I would say that while shell scripting is normally on-topic here, this case would not apply, because the type of work you are doing here is server-admin related, not really programming. I understand there is a little bit of cross-over here, but I suspect you would get better answers from Linux server admins.

Comment: Very well, we have also raised the issue (obviously) to Microstrategy. But thanks, I see why it was closed.